# How can I change the colors of this radial clock in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I found a JavaScript clock online. I want to change the color of the circles, but can't figure out how to do it.

This is the clock: https://codepen.io/Escu/pen/wMZpQz

This is the code where the circles are drawn:

```
Object.keys(circles).forEach((k, i) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    circles[k].update(times[k]);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + k.charCodeAt(0) * i + ", 50%, 50%)";
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

How can I change the colors of the circles? For example, the hours should be red, the minutes green and the seconds blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
var colors = [0, 77, 166];

//update circles, set their color, draw
Object.keys(circles).forEach((k, i) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    circles[k].update(times[k]);
    // hsl(hue, saturation, lightness)
    ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + colors[i] + ", 50%, 50%)";
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

You can use other color functions too, like:

```
var colors = ["blue", "#ff0000", "rgb(200, 0, 200)"];

//update circles, set their color, draw
Object.keys(circles).forEach((k, i) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    circles[k].update(times[k]);
    ctx.strokeStyle = colors[i];
    ctx.stroke();
});
```